# SSR distorts on camera movement

Tags: graphics, directx, hlsl, post-processing

Been working on implementing some simple screen space reflections and I feel I have the algorithm down correctly but I cannot seem to figure out why the reflections become distorted when the camera moves around. I use `CameraPos` to calculate the `camDir` which is where I thought the issue might have been however I also tried using a hardcoded value such as `float4(0.0, 5.0, -0.7)` and the result was the same that when the camera moves around the scene, the reflections become distorted. In some certain spots, depending on where the camera is, the reflections look correct. I'm wondering if anyone has come across something similar and could provide some insight into what I might be doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
// World space normal and positions
float3 normal = normalize(gNormal.Sample(sampleState, input.texCoord).xyz);
float4 WorldPos = float4(gPosition.SampleLevel(sampleState, input.texCoord, 0).xyz, 1.0);
float4 camDir = WorldPos - CameraPos;
float3 refDir = normalize(reflect(normalize(camDir.xyz), normal));

float noise(float2 seed)
{
    return frac(sin(dot(seed.xy, float2(12.9898, 78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}

// Calculating the reflection
float4 RayTrace(float3 reflectionWorld, const int maxCount, float stepSize, float3 pos, float2 uv)
{
    float4 color = float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    float3 step = stepSize * reflectionWorld;
    float4x4 projView = mul(V, P);
  
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxCount; i++)
    {
        float3 ray = (i + noise(uv + Time)) * step;
        float3 rayPos = pos + ray;
        float4 vpPos = mul(float4(rayPos, 1.0f), projView);
        float2 rayUv = vpPos.xy / vpPos.w * float2(0.5f, -0.5f) + float2(0.5f, 0.5f);

        float rayDepth = vpPos.z / vpPos.w;
        float gbufferDepth = gDepthBuffer.SampleLevel(sampleState, rayUv, 0).r;
        if (rayDepth - gbufferDepth > 0 && rayDepth - gbufferDepth < MaxThickness)
        {
            float a = 0.3f * pow(min(1.0, (stepSize * maxCount / 2) / length(ray)), 2.0);
            color = color * (1.0f - a) + float4(gDiffuse.SampleLevel(sampleState, rayUv, 0).rgb, 1.0) * a;
            break;
        }
    }

    return color;
}
```